# How can disabling modemmanager effect Gnome Desktop?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, modem-manager

I am running Ubuntu Server 18.04 on an Intel NUC which is also the host for my Home Assistant server.  Works great- I should have replaced my Raspberry Pi long ago.

While setting up Home Assistant, I was having problems with my USB Z-Wave stick (hub for my Z-Wave devices), but the solution was to disable modemmanager using *systemctl disable ModemManager.service*.
Works great...

However, I was also told "This however can have negative effects on distros with Gnome desktops so best advice is to disable the service."

I have a second NUC running Ubuntu Server, plus I installed the Gnome desktop.

Here's my question: How can disabling modemmanager effect Gnome Desktop??

Comment: Sounds like an unfounded rumor. You should ask whoever told that for clarifications.

Comment: That was in a comment on the Home Assistant git, but I haven't been able to find it again to ask the author.